# No kernel modules were found installing xubuntu from unetbootin

Tags: drivers, kernel, xubuntu, unetbootin

I'm trying to reinstall xubuntu after a bad install. Few questions. In bios install menu what is difference between "default" and "install xubuntu"? Also, I tried following default install, and I get the error "No kernel modules were found. This probably is due to a mismatch between the kernal used by this version of the installer and the kernel version of the archive" - what should I do?

- Absolute noob here, advise would be heavily appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know with certainty.

Unetbootin is one method of making a live USB and the program is what generates the menu items you are seeing.

Default is to run live, the other option, install ubuntu, it pulled from the options on the .iso. I think that option simply runs the installer without running a desktop environment.

I suggest you check the md5sum of the iso you downloaded

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Also, what version of Xubuntu?